# Run a formula on a set of ranges that are automatically defined within the formula in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here's a pic of my worksheet example:

[image: worksheet sample]

I would like the cell in C7 to say "White,Blue,Green"

And the cell in C11 to say "Black,White,Green" Using the exact same formula.

I would like the range to be automatically determined so I can use this formula for every parent product.

*More Info*

I already have code to combine cells of a given range from brettdj's [answer to a question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/404199), and it works great.

```
Function ConCat(ParamArray rng1()) As String
Dim X
Dim strOut As String
Dim strDelim As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
strDelim = ", "
For lngCnt = LBound(rng1) To UBound(rng1)
    If TypeOf rng1(lngCnt) Is Range Then
        If rng1(lngCnt).Cells.Count > 1 Then
            X = rng1(lngCnt).Value2
            For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
                For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
                    strOut = strOut & (strDelim & X(lngRow, lngCol))
                Next
            Next
        Else
            strOut = strOut & (strDelim & rng2.Value)
        End If
    End If
Next
ConCat = Right$(strOut, Len(strOut) - Len(strDelim))
End Function
```

Now I'm looking for a way to automatically select the range in 'B' by starting at the  **current row -1**, searching up the column for the **first blank space +1**, going down to **current row -1**.

Comment: Are you expecting a formula which you can fill down the whole column and it will only return a value in the "right" place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a UDF you can use `Application.Caller` (or `Application.ThisCell`) to get a reference to the containing cell, then you can move around from there...

```
Function ConCat() As String

    Application.Volatile 'Need this since there are no input 
                         '  parameters to trigger recalculation

    Const DELIM As String = ", "
    Dim s As String
    Dim rngF As Range

    On Error GoTo haveError

    'Where is the firmula being called from?
    Set rngF = Application.Caller

    'Move to the correct column
     Set rngF = rngF.Offset(0,-1)         'use an offset
    'Set rngF=rngF.EntireRow.Cells(1,"Y") 'use a fixed column

    'Exit if not in a good starting location
    If rngF.Value <> "" Then Exit Function

    'Move up until we're below the next space up
    Do While rngF.Offset(-1, 0) <> ""
        Set rngF = rngF.Offset(-1, 0)
    Loop
    'Move down from there, adding to the string
    Do While rngF.Value <> ""
        s = s & IIf(s <> "", DELIM, "") & rngF.Value
        Set rngF = rngF.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ConCat = s
    Exit Function

haveError:

    'If you use this formula when there's no space to go "up"
    '  or "left" then it will error on the Offset() call...

    ConCat = "Err!" 'or just return an empty string if you prefer

End Function
```

Comment: Oh wow, this works spectacularly! I assume if I were to adapt this to my actual sheet, I just have to increase the offset to have it grab from the correct columns, right? Or can I just hardcode "column y" for example?
Again, thanks a lot for the code!

Comment: Yes you would just adjust to suit.  You can hard-code a column rather than use an offset if that's easier.  See my edit for that (the commented line)